# System error after installing from setup file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I created a c program in visual studio 2015 and I made a setup file
the setup file works fine in my computer . So i decided to sent the setup file to my friend , though the setup file was installed successfully when we run the program it shows system error **"the program can't star because VCRUNTIME140D.dll is missing from your computer.Try re-installing the program"**

here is the program I wrote ( which works perfectly )

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void beg();
void beg2();
void beg3();
void beg4();
void beg5();
void beg6();
void beg7();
void beg8();
void beg9();
void beg10();
void store_a();
void the_end();
void wrong();
void right();
void help();
int i,m;
char b[101],a[101];
void main()
{
    int diff;
    i = 0;
    printf("\n WELCOME THO THE GAME \n"); //welcome 
    printf(" ARE YOU READY !!\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\n 1.play\t 2.help\t 3.exit\n"); //menu
        printf(" Enter your option : ");
        scanf(" %d", &diff);
        switch (diff)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                beg();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                help();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (diff != 3);
}
void beg()
{
    int b;
    m = 2;
    printf("\n what is the capital of india?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.New Delhi\n 2.Mumbai\n 3.Kochi\n 4.Chennai\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b == 1)
    {
        right();
        beg2();
    }
    else
    {
        wrong();
        beg2();
    }
}
void beg2()
{
    int b;
    m = 3;
    printf("\n 12 + 11 = ?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.12\n 2.45\n 3.23\n 4.17\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b != 3)
    {
        b = 2;
        wrong();
        beg3();
    }
    else
    {
        while (b == 3)
        {
            if (b == 3)
            {
                right();
                beg3();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void beg3()
{
    int b;
    m = 4;
    printf("\n who is the prime minister of india ?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.Pranab Mukherjee\n 2.narendra modi\n 3.manmohan singh\n 4.steven thomas\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b != 2)
    {
        b = 1;
        wrong();
        beg4();
    }
    else
    {
        while (b == 2)
        {
            if (b == 2)
            {
                right();
                beg4();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void beg4()
{
    int b;
    m = 5;
    printf("\n 5 x 7 = ?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.32\n 2.54\n 3.25\n 4.35\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b != 4)
    {
        b = 1;
        wrong();
        beg5();
    }
    else
    {
        while (b == 4)
        {
            if (b == 4)
            {
                right();
                beg5();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void beg5()
{
    int b;
    m = 6;
    printf("\n which country is paris the capital of?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.India\n 2.France\n 3.England\n 4.China\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b != 2)
    {
        b = 1;
        wrong();
        beg6();
    }
    else
    {
        while (b == 2)
        {
            if (b == 2)
            {
                right();
                beg6();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void beg6()
{
    int b;
    m = 7;
    printf("\n what is the capital of america?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.Los Angeles\n 2.New York \n 3.Washington, D.C.\n 4.Las Vegas\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b != 3)
    {
        b = 1;
        wrong();
        beg7();
    }
    else
    {
        while (b == 3)
        {
            if (b == 3)
            {
                right();
                beg7();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void beg7()
{
    int b;
    m = 8;
    printf("\n what is the highest mountain in the world?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.Mount Everest\n 2.Kangchenjunga \n 3.Annapurna\n 4.K2 \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b != 1)
    {
        b = 3;
        wrong();
        beg8();
    }
    else
    {
        while (b == 1)
        {
            if (b == 1)
            {
                right();
                beg8();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void beg8()
{
    int b;
    m = 9;
    printf("\n who invented piano?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.serin thomas\n 2.Bartolomeo Cristofori \n 3.annrose pino\n 4.Baldwin pinero \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b != 2)
    {
        b = 3;
        wrong();
        beg9();
    }
    else
    {
        while (b == 2)
        {
            if (b == 2)
            {
                right();
                beg9();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void beg9()
{
    int b;
    m = 10;
    printf("\n what is the answer of ( 3-3 x 6+2 )?\n");
    printf(" options\n");
    printf(" 1.-17\n 2. 0 \n 3. -13\n 4. 9 \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b != 3)
    {
        b = 1;
        printf("\n Do you want to know the correct answer for the qustion :\n1.yes\n2.no\t: ");
        scanf("%d", &opt);
        if (opt == 1)
        {
            printf("\n The correct answer is as follows:\n Question: 3 – 3 x 6 + 2\n Multiplication first : 3 – 18 + 2\n Left to right : -15 + 2\n Answer : -13\n");
        }
        wrong();
        beg10();
    }
    else
    {
        while (b == 3)
        {
            if (b == 3)
            {
                right();
                beg10();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void beg10()
{
    int len,i,f;
    store_a();
    printf("\n A man has a barrel with filled with oil that weighs 100 pounds,\n and then he puts something into it.\n Now the barrel weighs less than 100 pounds.\n What did he put in the barrel ?? \n");
    printf(" enter the answer :");
    scanf("%s", b);
    len = strlen(b);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[i])
        {
            f = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            f = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (f == 1)
    {
        printf("The answer is correct!!\n");
        the_end();
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" Wrong answer\nthe correct ans was 'hole'\n");
        the_end();
    }

}
void wrong()
{
    printf("wrong answer !!\n");
    printf("your score is :%d\n", i);
    printf("\n qustion number: %d", m);
}//when the option is wrong
void the_end()
{
    printf("\n***congratulations***\n");
    printf(" your final score is :%d\n", i);
}//at the end of the game
void right()
{
    printf("the answer is correct !!\n");
    i++;
    printf("your score is :%d\n", i);
    printf("\n qustion number: %d", m);
}//when the ans is correct
void help()
{
    int opt;
    printf("\n 1.How to play\t2.About\t3.Main menu\n");
    printf(" enter your option : ");
    scanf("%d", &opt);
    if (opt == 1)
    {
        printf(" answer the qustions..\n you get 1 point for each qustion..\n there is a total of 10 qustions try to get the maximum marks\n good luck \n");
        help();
    }
    else if (opt == 2)
    {
        printf("\tCREATED BY\n **STEVEN THOMAS** \n **steventhomaspuli@gmail.com**\n ");
        help();
    }
    else if (opt == 3)
    {
        main();
    }
}//help menu
void store_a()
{
    a[0] = 'h';
    a[1] = 'o';
    a[2] = 'l';
    a[3] = 'e';
}
```

and this is the setup file I created 
[click here to download](http://www.mediafire.com/file/klrlp62s40fl42y/Quiz.rar)

pls tell me what is wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had built and shipped debug version of your program. Debug VC runtime is not a part of VC redistributable package, so your friend get a message about missing DLLs. Build and ship release version.

Comment: I created a setup file of release version of my program , now which files I should share in order to work on different PC's

Comment: Only your project executables and dlls. You may also include VC runtime redistributable (it is available on the Microsoft site for all VS versions).